# Spark SQL - Select all AND computed columns?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is a total noob question, sorry for that. In Spark, I can use select as:

```
df.select("*"); //to select everything
df.select(df.col("colname")[, df.col("colname")]); //to select one or more columns
df.select(df.col("colname"), df.col("colname").plus(1)) //to select a column and a calculated column
```

But. How can I select all the columns PLUS a calculated one? Obviously
`select("*", df.col("colname").plus(1))` doesn't work (compilation error). How can this be done under JAVA?
Thank you!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just do:

```
df.select(df.col("*"), df.col("colName").plus(1));
```

Comment: import co in using pyspark: `from pyspark.sql.functions import col`

Comment: Usually I prefer the `withColumn` solutions below. However, if you want to unpack a struct column, this is the best way I know. I.e. `df.select(df.col("*"), df.col("colName.*"))` where colName has multiple (named) values.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `withColumn()` method, this will create a new column to the DataFrame.

```
df.select("*")
  .withColumn("ColName", col("colName").plus(1))
```

Comment: I personally prefer this one.  Puts all my computed columns together.

Comment: You can directly add a column on the dataframe without doing select
`df.withColumn("ColName", col("colName").plus(1))`

Answer (score 1):

The difference between .select() and .withColumn() methods is that .select() returns only the columns you specify, while .withColumn() returns all the columns of the DataFrame in addition to the one you defined.

You can directly use **withColumn**:

```
df.withColumn("ColName", col("colName").plus(1))
```